# UITableViewCell doesn't exist when scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi everyone !

I'm facing a problem with UITableView...
I've got a registration form which doesn't fit the screen, so the user has to scroll down to fill it entirely. When the user scrolls down, the cells at the top of the screen don't appear anymore and the problem occurs : that's impossible to get their content ( which is a custom UITextField ).

Do you know if there is a way to tell the system " hey I'd like to get my cell's contents even if they don't appear on the screen because of scrolling " ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `UITableViewCell`s are re-used once they leave the screen so never store any unbacked data in them. Always store data in your model and populate the cells as they appear on-screen. Why don't you just use a `UIScrollView` instead? It seems more suited for a registration form anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't get the data directly from the cell. Store the values in properties or a model object using UITextfieldDelegate for example so your are not dependant of the cell still existing or not.